# Unable to run any Python program using code runner

Tags: python, coderunner

I'm brand new to coding.  I managed to figure out how to use github and I have been forking projects over to my machine in an attempt to play around with them and learn python.  My problem is every single project I fork over, when I run any of the .py files in Coderunner it pops up with errors and doesn't run correctly.

Is this because coderunner is not capable of running these programs?  Or do I have to run the programs through terminal to get them functioning correctly?

Comment: every project is different, usually the run/build instructions are somewhere in `INSTALL` or `README` files. terminal is usually the way to go

Comment: in addition to the previous comment, there are `setup.py` files. And if you post the code youtrying to run and error you getting, we will be glad to help you, othewise, we can't

Comment: I guess my question is..  Is Coderunner even capable of running a full python project with multiple files in it, or is Coderunner more meant for like quick testing of code?

Answer (score 1):

Coderunner is more useful in testing single python files instead of larger projects, however it can run such projects.  A larger project should have a `setup.py` or a `main.py` which should be run.  Also, what errors are you getting?